# Plotting a function's derivative with Sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to take a plot a derivative of a function with sympy. Although plotting the actual function was ok, I cannot plot the derivative of it.

```
# Solve u function for t
eq = m*sp.diff(u, t, 2) + c*sp.diff(u, t) + k*u
u_sol = sp.dsolve(eq, u).subs({k: sol1[0][1], c: sol1[0][2]})

# Plot the graph of u(t) (assuming constants are 1)
# t needs to start from 0 

assumed_func1 = u_sol.rhs.subs({C1: 1, C2: 1})
plot(assumed_func1, xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(-5, 5), title="u(t)") # This works

assumed_func2 = sp.diff(u_sol, t).subs({C1: 1, C2: 1})
plot(assumed_func2, xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(-5, 5), title="u'(t)") # This does not work
```

Tried to plot the differential of a function. But i got a this error instead:

```
function.py", line 1339, in __new__
    raise ValueError(filldedent('''
ValueError:
Can't calculate derivative wrt -10.0000000000000.
```

I believe, problem occurs while t takes a negative value. I tried to solve it by using

```
xlim=(0, 10)
```

but it did not change.

Comment: The code is incomplete so hard to say exactly what the problem is but the error message indicates that the second argument to diff is the number `-10.0` when it should be a symbol.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`u_sol` is an object of type `Equality`, which has a left hand side and a right hand side.

When you execute this code, I assume that you would like to apply the derivative to both sides of `u_sol`. Unfortunately, SymPy is currently unable to do so:

```py
assumed_func2 = sp.diff(u_sol, t).subs({"C1": 1, "C2": 1})
```

So you end up with a derivative of an equality, which sympy doesn't know how to plot.

What you have to do is differentiate only the right hand side of `u_sol`:

```py
assumed_func2 = sp.diff(u_sol.rhs, t).subs({"C1": 1, "C2": 1})
```

Then, the plot command should work.